# This template uses shell, which doesn't yet support UWp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, uwp-xaml, iso

[image]

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Shell support is only provided for Android and iOS at this time.

Comment: I need to create a mac app how I can do that?

Comment: @MissionImpossible Mac app? or a Windows UWP app?

Comment: Mac os software.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: @MissionImpossible You can look at Preview: Bringing macOS to Xamarin.Forms | Xamarin Blog : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/  Note: Xamarin Shell only supports iOS, Android, and UWP (experimental, see docs on how to enable), it does not support Xamarin.Mac.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a mac app how I can do that?

MSFT provide document that make xamarin.mac app, and here is xamarin.mac [startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac). the following are default requirements

Xamarin.Mac application development requires:

1. A Mac computer running macOS High Sierra (10.13) or higher.
2. Xcode 10 or higher.
3. The latest version of Xamarin.Mac and Visual Studio for Mac.

To run an application built with Xamarin.Mac, you will need:

A Mac computer running macOS 10.7 or greater

Comment: Is there any way I can build on windows?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't build it in windows environment, because it building a bundle requires invoking the native toolchain  that is macOS only